# Последовательный обход TreeSet Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, дерево

Как реализовать последовательный обход дерева на Java?
(TreeSet)

Comment: А чем вас итератор не устраивает?

Comment: задание такое... "Тип обхода: последовательный"

Comment: Что вы подразумевает под последовательным? Дерево хранит данные в отсортированом виде. Пройтись по нему вы можете или итератором или `for each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам правильно сказали по поводу итераторов. Множества Set (TreeSet) реализуют базовый интерфейс Collection, который в свою очередь реализует Iterable. Это значит что перебирать можно for each

```
Set<String> ts = new TreeSet<>();
        ts.add("s1");
        ts.add("s0");
        for (String s : ts) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```